# Camlp4 example : unbound module Printers.Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

i'm exploring Camlp4 following [this](http://ambassadortothecomputers.blogspot.it/p/reading-camlp4.html) useful series of blog posts, but I'm having compilation problems.
This is the code of my test.ml file :

```
open Camlp4.PreCast

let _loc = Loc.ghost in

let cons =
 let rec loop () =
   try
     match read_line () with
       | "" -> []
       | c -> c :: loop ()
   with End_of_file -> [] in
 loop () in
 Printers.Ocaml.print_implem
 <:str_item<
    type t =
    $Ast.TySum (_loc,
           Ast.tyOr_of_list
             (List.map
                 (fun c -> <:ctyp< $uid:c$ >>)
                 cons))$
    let to_string = function
    $Ast.mcOr_of_list
    (List.map
          (fun c -> <:match_case< $uid:c$ -> $`str:c$ >>)
        cons)$
    let of_string = function
    $let ors =
   Ast.mcOr_of_list
     (List.map
         (fun c -> <:match_case< $`str:c$ -> $uid:c$ >>)
         cons) in
    Ast.McOr(_loc,
           ors,
             <:match_case< _ -> invalid_arg "bad string" >>)$
>>
```

I'm using this compilation command: 
ocamlc -pp camlp4of -I +camlp4  -o variant camlp4lib.cma test.ml
but ocamlc emits :
Error: Unbound module Printers.Ocaml

I guess is a matter of compilation command but I don't find where Printers.Ocaml is implemented.

thank you for your help!
_
Fr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access to `Camlp4.PreCast.Printers.OCaml.print_implem`, accessible after your `open Camlp4.PreCast` as `Printers.OCaml.print_implem`; note the different capitalization of `OCaml` vs `Ocaml`; `OCaml` is standard and should be consistently used across OCaml tools and documentation (you can file a minor bug report if some library distributed with the compiler breaks the convention).

PS: for your information, the next version of OCaml (4.01) will probably print the following error message (tested with the development version)

```
File "test.ml", line 13, characters 1-43:
Error: Unbound module Camlp4.PreCast.Printers.Ocaml
Did you mean OCaml?
```

Comment: yes, it was, disappointingly. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my error 
the mudule Printers.Ocaml does not exist, Printers.OCaml (with uppercase C) exists.

I was trying for 2 days on this.

Solved.